# How scikit learn initializes the weight vector for MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I want to know how `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` initializes the weight vector. In the documentation [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), there is nothing mentioned about how the weight vector is initialized by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L300):

```python
def _init_coef(self, fan_in, fan_out):
    if self.activation == 'logistic':
        # Use the initialization method recommended by
        # Glorot et al.
        init_bound = np.sqrt(2. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    elif self.activation in ('identity', 'tanh', 'relu'):
        init_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    else:
        # this was caught earlier, just to make sure
        raise ValueError("Unknown activation function %s" %
                         self.activation)

    coef_init = self._random_state.uniform(-init_bound, init_bound,
                                           (fan_in, fan_out))
    intercept_init = self._random_state.uniform(-init_bound, init_bound,
                                                fan_out)
    return coef_init, intercept_init
```

The mentioned method is described in the [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html): `Glorot, X. & Bengio, Y.. (2010). Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks. Proceedings of the Thirteenth International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics, in PMLR 9:249-256`